# Test used bean instead mock object

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, spring-test

I start work with `Spring` and `Mockito`.
I use `JUnit`, `Mockito`, `Spring boot`.
I have test for controller, and try to make it work.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CommonConfiguration.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "embedded")
public class UserController_IntegrationWContainer_Tests {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

@MockBean(name = "SignatureValidator")
private SignatureValidator signatureValidator;

private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
...

@Before
public void before() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).dispatchOptions(true).build();
    this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
}

@Test
public void createConfirmation() throws Exception {

    ...

    ConfirmationDetails signature = new ConfirmationDetails("signature");
    when(this.signatureValidator.validateAndEnforceSignature(signature))
            .thenReturn("advanced");

    mockMvc.perform(post("/distributions/1/receive")
            .content(this.objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(signature))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .andExpect(status().is(201));
}
```

This test class used for test `UserController`.

```
@RestController
@Validated
@Transactional
public class UserController {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);
    private UserService userService;
    private SignatureValidator signatureValidator;
    ...

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService, SignatureValidator signatureValidator, ...) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.signatureValidator = signatureValidator;
        ...
    }  
    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/distributions/{distributionId}/receive",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> confirmReceipt(
            @RequestBody ConfirmationDetails signature,
            @Context HttpServletRequest request,
            @Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 19, message = "ID cannot exceed 19 digits")
            @Min(value = 1, message = "ID must be > 0")
            @PathVariable("distributionId") Long distributionId) {

        logger.info("Processing request confirmReceipt");

        /*for this string I want to use stub. but stub doesn't work*/
        String advancedSignature = signatureValidator.validateAndEnforceSignature(signature);

        ...

        Map<String, String> resultsMap = new HashMap<>();
        resultsMap.put("code", "RECEIPT_SIGNED");
        resultsMap.put("message", "Distribution download confirmed");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(resultsMap, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }    
}
```

SignatureValidator interface:

```
public interface SignatureValidator {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    String validateAndEnforceSignature(ConfirmationDetails signature);
}
```

Two implementations of SignatureValidator:

```
@Component
public class SignatureValidatorIml extends WebServiceGatewaySupport implements SignatureValidator {
...
}

@Component
public class SignatureValidatorJinn extends WebServiceGatewaySupport implements SignatureValidator {
...
}
```

Spring decide what implementation of bean need to inject using JinnServerConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
public class JinnServerConfiguration {

    final Environment env;

    @Autowired
    public JinnServerConfiguration(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        ...
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpComponentsMessageSender messageSender() {
        ...
        return messageSender;
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("!local")
    public SignatureValidator signatureValidator(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller,
                                                 HttpComponentsMessageSender messageSender) {
        SignatureValidatorJinn signatureValidatorJinn = new SignatureValidatorJinn(env);
        signatureValidatorJinn.setDefaultUri("http://.../SignatureValidationService");
        signatureValidatorJinn.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        signatureValidatorJinn.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        signatureValidatorJinn.setMessageSender(messageSender);
        return signatureValidatorJinn;
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("local")
    public SignatureValidator signatureValidatorLocal(){
        return new SignatureValidatorIml();
    }

}
```

For all services in UserController mock works fine.
But when I want to mock `SignatureValidator`, it is not work. 
In debug mode I see, that in test it used mocked bean, but then UserController runs it used Spring bean (`SignatureValidatorJinn`) instead mocked bean.

Why it used SignatureValidatorJinn? I think it so because test class has annotation: @ActiveProfiles(profiles = "embedded"). And according to JinnServerConfiguration "@Profile("!local")" spring made this decision.

This test worked fine, until annotation `@Component` has been added to `SignatureValidatorIml` class and to `SignatureValidatorJinn` class.

I can't understand, why it used Spring bean. Because other service mock work fine. I found many information about mock, but can't find a solution of this problem.

I try to do next thing, but they didn't help:

- don't use MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
- qualify current bean for SignatureValidator: Jinn or Iml;
- use @InjectMocks UserController userController;

**EDIT**

If I delete @Component annotation in SignatureValidatorJinn and SignatureValidatorIml, it works nice. But I can't understand why is it so.

For example, class UserService annotated with "@Service". And it is successfully mocking.

So, maybe somebody can explain, why "@Component" doesn't allow to create mock object in this case?

**EDIT2**

**The problem was solved**

I can't delete annotation component, because without this annotation, DI in my application will not work. 
I find decision. Bean is called signatureValidator. And I use name SignatureValidator to specificate bean to mock. *That was mistake )* So with follow construction it works fine:

```
@MockBean(name = "signatureValidator") 
private SignatureValidator signatureValidator;
```

Thanks everyone for replies :)

Comment: I can't understand how did your application inject `SignatureValidator` into `UserController` since you have declared 2 concrete `SignatureValidator`s. if you want to deploy your application successfully you must use the specialized name on `@Qualifier` in `UserController`. however your test `@MockBean`'s name is not same as the value in your `@Qualifier`. Why didn't you put the `UserController` here?

Comment: @holi-java, thank you for your answer. I update question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to mock `SignatureValidator` bean. But you have and use two beans `SignatureValidatorJinn` and `SignatureValidatorIml`. And your controllers use the two beans. 
Try to mock one of SignatureValidatorJinn and SignatureValidatorIml.

```
@MockBean(name = "SignatureValidatorJinn")
private SignatureValidator signatureValidatorJinn;
```

or

```
@MockBean(name = "SignatureValidatorIml")
private SignatureValidator signatureValidatorIml;
```

that is used in your `post("/distributions/1/receive")` request.

Comment: Konstantin, thank you. I tried to use both, but it didn't help.

Comment: Does it help if you don't mock the interface `SignatureValidator` but the concrete classes `SignatureValidatorIml` and `SignatureValidatorJinn`?

Comment: I try 
 @MockBean(name = "SignatureValidatorJinn")
 private SignatureValidatorJinn signatureValidator;
and 
 @MockBean(name = "SignatureValidatorIml")
 private SignatureValidatorIml signatureValidator;
And it didn't work too.

Comment: Dmitry, I think you have a lot of `SignatureValidator` and can't mock the same is used in your request. It can help if you add the place in the your question with injecting the bean `SignatureValidator` in the request processing. Also, you can inspect your application context with Spring Boot Actuator and endpoint `beans` to find beans to mock.

Comment: @Konstantin, I update question post with adding vacant information.
Thank you for your advise use Spring Boot Actuator. It's interesting tool.

Comment: Please delete `@Component` for classes: `@Component` - Indicates that an annotated class is a "component". Such classes are considered as candidates for auto-detection when using annotation-based configuration and classpath scanning.
Also, you can mock the bean with the next name:
    @MockBean(name = "signatureValidator"
    private SignatureValidator signatureValidatorIml;

Comment: @Konstantin, you right. If I delete Component annotation, it works nice.
But I can't understand why is it so.
For example, class  UserService annotated with "@Service". And he is successfully mocking. 
So, why "@Component" doesn't allow to create mock object in this case?

Comment: @Konstantin, I can't delete annotation component, because without this annotation, DI in my application will not work.
But I find decision. Bean is called signatureValidator. And I use name SignatureValidator to specificate bean to mock. That was mistake )
So with follow construction it works fine:

@MockBean(name = "signatureValidator")
private SignatureValidator signatureValidator;

Comment: @DmitryAlifanov You use two different way beans creation in one application. If you inspect that bean is injected in RestController you can right mock it. Now you create certainty with beans when you delete `@Component`. 
Also, you can delete `@Autowire` on constructor because now Spring injects beans in a constructor for RestController automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You must not call

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

because the `SpringRunner` already initializes the mocks. By calling `initMocks` you assign a new object to `signatureValidator`. All Mockito actions like `when` and `verify` are performed on the new object, but Spring still uses the "old" `SignatureValidator` that was created by the `SpringRunner`.

Comment: Stefan, thank you. I try not use initMocks, but it didn't help.